# Getting RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #7: You must supply a layout_width attribute

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm trying to use a ListView inside of a Linear Layout but when I run my app I get a runtimeexception with the message:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #7: You must supply a layout_width attribute.

Error at adapter  when inflating ListItem Layout.
This issue is on kitkat version 4.4
     This is ListItem.xml layout ----

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/img_client_logo"
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/drawer_img_size_width"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/drawer_img_size_hight"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                            />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_client_name"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/drawer_textsize"
                            android:text=""
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
                            android:textColor="@color/white" />

                    </LinearLayout>
```

We have used `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` in my style.xml for application Theme because we have use Toolbar in place of Action bar.

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/actionbar_colour</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/actionbar_colour</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Can you post  your logcat?

Comment: " This is ListItem.xml layout" -- no, it is not. It is not even valid XML. If you want help with the layout, please post the *complete layout*.

Comment: Thank for showing intrest..I have updated my ListItem.xml Layout.

Comment: add orientation attribute to linearlayout and also xml filename should have all small characters.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem in your dimens file. Please check out that you specified dp in your dimens (it will cause an error if you write only number without dp postfix). Your dimens must look like:

```
<dimen name="drawer_img_size_width">48dp</dimen>
```

not like:

```
<dimen name="drawer_img_size_width">48</dimen>
```